# Generating an expiry date based on fields in different tables

Tags: ms-access

I want a field that gives the date a certificate expires.

I think i would create a query and add a field using something like this..

```
dateadd("d", [DaysToExpire], [DateCompleted])
```

My trouble is, `[DaysToExpire]` is on a different table to `[DateCompleted]`. how do i resolve that?

Is there a way to get the query field to refer to both tables?

Can I create a lookup field on one of the tables that auto populates once the 2 tables a linked by a record?

I am all pretty new to this so sorry if my language is a bit off. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code generated by access:

```
SELECT tbl_Courses.CourseName
     , tbl_Courses.CourseDescription
     , tbl_Training.DateCompleted
  FROM tbl_Courses 
 INNER JOIN tbl_Training 
    ON tbl_Courses.CourseID = tbl_Training.CourseID;
```

Error after entering Mr.Brownstone's code:

[image]

Comment: [Nope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Here we prefer DDL and DML for tables and data! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Are you calculating expirydate in tbl_training with the dateadd?

Comment: @Vérace Thank you. I'll look into those formats for posting info.

Comment: @Sam I was trying to do the datadd in a query. Trying to put it in the highlighted section of the image above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-view-statement-microsoft-access-sql) using a [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) statement to combine the results of two related tables. In your design, the `CourseID` field appears on both the `tbl_courses` and `tbl_training` tables, using this field to perform the join you can easily derive the value that you require:

```
CREATE VIEW [CourseDetails] 
(
    [CourseName], 
    [CourseDescription], 
    [DateCompleted], 
    [ExpiryDate]
)
AS
SELECT tbl_Courses.[CourseName]
     , tbl_Courses.[CourseDescription]
     , tbl_Training.[DateCompleted]
     , DATEADD("d", tbl_Training.[DaysToExpire], tbl_Courses.[DateCompleted]) [ExpiryDate]
  FROM tbl_Courses 
 INNER JOIN tbl_Training 
    ON tbl_Courses.[CourseID] = tbl_Training.[CourseID];
```

There is a full [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_sql_view.htm) on how to perform this that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Your code is beyond me unfortunately. Maybe I've bitten off more than I can chew. I am trying to create the query using the designer within access(see new image). I thought I could just enter a small amount of code into the highlight section of the image to get the date.

Comment: Locate the SQL that is generated, and you should be able to copy & paste my script in to get the desired result.

Comment: I did give that a try but it didn't work. Got a syntax error. I'll upload the error. It may just be too hard for a novice like me. Should I accept your answer? To get this tied up?

Comment: I've updated the answer, generally that error message is shown when there are not square brackets (quoted identifiers) around field names.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. After I "OK" the error, when im taken back to the SQL the [ExpiryDate] is highlighted.

Comment: As an alternate work around. Can I create a field on the Training table that auto populates with the [DaysToExpire] from the Courses table when a training record is created and a course is selected? Then I would have both bit of data on the same table and creating the query would be easy for me.

Comment: @CTRANS I've updated my answer with additional details which you might find helpful.

Comment: Ms Access does not support views.